# How do we interpret the "natural log of income"

Tags: regression, least-squares

I'm just confused as to how we interpret a natural log in relation to a regressor, say years of training
thanks

Answer (score 5):

Let $y$ be income and $x$ be years of training.  It sounds like you are thinking about

$$ \log(y)  = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x $$

Exponentiating both sides yields

$$ y = B_0 \exp(\beta_1 x) $$

Where $B_0 = \exp(\beta_0)$ is the median income when individuals have 0 years of training (why median and not mean?  I will get to that).

So how do we interpret this regression.  When $x$ increases by $1/\beta_1$ units, then the median income increases by a factor of $e$.  Consider someone with 0 years of training and compare then to someone with $1/\beta_1$ years of training.

The median income of the latter person is $y_1 = B_0 \exp(\beta_1 \times \frac{1}{\beta_1}) = B_0 \exp(1)$.  The median income for the former person is $y_0 = B_0 \exp(0) = B_0 = y_1/\exp(1)$.  Hence, the median income has increased by a factor of $e$

### Why The Median And Not The Mean?

OLS does not require the residuals to be normally distributed (or even independent of one another).  That being said, some assumptions on the conditional distribution can give us some insight.

If we assume the conditional distribution is normal, then this means $\log(y) \vert x$ is normal and hence $y \vert x$ is lognormal.  [According to some results about the log normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), if $\mu$ is the expectation of the underlying normal random variable, then $\exp(\mu)$ is the median of the lognormal *not the mean*.  To get the mean, we would have to estimate the residual variance and multiply our prediction by a factor of $\exp(\sigma^2/2)$.  The relationship between changes in the predictor and changes in the expectation of the log normal random variable are the same as the median since the effects are multiplicative.

Comment: thanks, how about if we used dummy variables instead, how would that affect interpretation

Comment: @king34  A dummy variable would change the median income by a factor of $\exp(\beta)$, where $\beta$ is the estimated coefficient.